# Avoid re-conversion of a UTF-8 String PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, decode

**Well,** I have a BD with a lot of ISO strings and another with UTF-8 (yes, I ruin everything) and now I'm making a custom function that rewrite all the BD again to have all in UTF-8, the problem, is the conversion with UTF-8 strings... The ? appears:

[image: An example]

```
$field = $fila['Field'];
            $acon = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `$field` as content FROM `$curfila` WHERE id='$i'"));
            $content = $acon['content'];
            if(!is_numeric($content)) {
                if($content != null) {
                    if(ip2long($content) === false) {
                        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
                        if(mb_detect_encoding($content) === "UTF-8") {
                            $sanitized = utf8_decode($content);
                            if($sanitized != $content) {
                                echo 'Fila [ID ('.$i.')] <b>'.$field.'</b> => '.$sanitized.'<br>';
                                //mysql_query("UPDATE `$curfila` SET `$field`='$sanitized' WHERE id='$i'");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**PD:** I check all the columns and rows of all the tables of the BD. (I show all everything before doing anything)

So, how can I detect that?

I tried mb_detect_encoding, but the all the string are in UTF-8... So, which function can I use now?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: So, you have *one table* with *one column* and in that column you have some strings which were inserted correctly and appear okay and others which were inserted incorrectly and are messed up?! And you want to convert those that are messed up, but not those that are okay? Or are the ones which are messed up and those that are okay cleanly separated into different columns?

Comment: Yes, well I had a problem before, and is that I used SET NAMES utf8 a time after I have some activity on my web, and when I reaslised you can imagine how was everything meshed up. The answer to your questions is the first question you said.

You can check it at http://pastebin.com/c9N4NbAT

Comment: Should've converted all the data that was already in your database *before* you switched to correctly inserting data. Let that be a lesson. </schadenfreude> ;)

Comment: I'd think the best you can do now is something along the lines of statistical analysis. It's all valid text in a valid encoding, so it's not really possible to detect whether it's correct or not without looking at the content itself. Can't you use a cutoff date? All data inserted before the switch was bad, all after is good?

Comment: I solved it, simply re-checking if the accents still exists after a second conversion. The correct string after a conversion will corrupt and the accents will disappear, so the question is solved and closed.